# I can't get post parameters via Request.form aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I have this page Default.aspx:

```
<%
    Dim name_a = Request.Form("fname_a")

    Dim name_b = Request.Form("fname_b")

%>

 <form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname_a"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>



  <form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fname_b"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
  </form>
```

But I can't get the result of the fname_b, it always return **Nothing**.

Is there a restriction when using more than one form method="post" with the same action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit button submits the `form` that it is contained in. This form will only post the data from the inputs that it contains.

You should find that clicking `Submit` gives you the data for `name_a`, whereas clicking `Submit2` gives you the data for `name_b`.

Combining these into one form would allow both inputs to be read:

```
<%
    Dim name_a = Request.Form("fname_a")

    Dim name_b = Request.Form("fname_b")
%>

 <form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname_a"><br>
    <%--<input type="submit" value="Submit">--%>

      First Name: <input type="text" name="fname_b"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit2">
  </form>
```

You could have two forms, but keep in mind that only the values for the submitted one will come through. You would also need to be check which form has been submitted before any actions are taken on the data to ensure there are no errors that arise from working on `nothing`.